# Strict less than operator in LDAP search filter?

Tags: ldap

In all references on LDAP search filter operator I find `<=` for "less than or equal to" and `>=` for "greater than or equal to."

Is there really no "strictly less than" operator? Must I write `attribute < threshold` as the following? (Threshold is a fixed value.)

```
(&(attribute <= threshold)(!(attribute = threshold)))
```

In my current case the attribute values are integers that represent dates, e.g. `20120217161853` for 2012-02-17 16:18:53.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another simple workaround would to to invert the condition. If you need

```
(attribute < threshold)
```

Then this could also be written as

```
!(attribute >= threshold)
```

Comment: Some LDAP servers do not allow any spaces around the operator.

Answer (score 6):

Consult [RFC4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.5) for definitions of the types of search filters. The types of filters are:

- equalityMatch AttributeValueAssertion,
- substrings SubstringFilter
- greaterOrEqual  AttributeValueAssertion
- lessOrEqual     AttributeValueAssertion
- present         AttributeDescription
- approxMatch     AttributeValueAssertion
- extensibleMatch MatchingRuleAssertion

Not only is there no '<' filter, the relative values in `>=` and `<=` are defined by ordering rules, and so making a relative value comparison may not be what is expected unless `treshold` has `1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27` syntax and has the `integerOrderingMatch` ordering rule.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Actually "threshold" is a fixed value and not another attribute, sorry for not making it clear. Does the ordering rule have to be `integerOrderingMatch` though?

Comment: No, only for integer comparisons. Other ordering rules for attributes might be lexicographic. Applications must consult the schema to determine the ordering rules, matching rules, and attribute syntax. The object identifiers used in the schema are defined at the IANA.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure to really understand. If you want somthing like `X<100` why don't you code `X<=99`.

Comment: That should work. I didn't think of it because the input happens to be a date-time string, but once it's stored in LDAP it's all just integers.

Comment: Which Directory are you using ?

Comment: The directory is our client's and I think it's a Sun Directory Server, but we don't have access to it yet... For now we run our tests against `Net::LDAP::Server::Test`, it's a Perl module that implements just enough of a directory server for testing.